# conditional probability that randomly chosen

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

In a certain village sports club, 46 % of members play football, 36 % of members play cricket, and 17 % of members play both games. What is the probability (between 0 and 1) that a randomly chosen member does not play football given that he/she plays cricket?

Give your solution accurate to 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be the event that the person plays football and $C$ be the event they play cricket. Then, what you want is
$$
P(F^c | C) = \frac{P(F^c \cap C)}{P(C)}.
$$
Now, $P(F^c \cap C) = P(\text{the person plays cricket, but not football})$, which you can calculate, since you know that 17% play both cricket and football.